How to trigger Nx Release on apps/* when changes made to dependent libs/* modules?
Im experimenting with nx release and cannot figure out how make the command release an app when I make a change to a dependent module.
Looking at the below graph, you can see i have 3 apps, 2 are dependent on the shared-ui module.

If I make direct changes to the apps, nx release detects the changes (via conventional commits) and continues as expected. I've now made a change to the shared-ui module and committed it as fix(shared-ui): made a change. I expected that task-management-web and sales-orders-web would have their patch version incremented, but nx release does not detect any changes.

The changes to shared-ui are being done in a branch. The list of affected apps is correct;
$ nx show projects --type app --affected
sales-orders-web
company-web

but nx release does not detect the changes.
Even explicitly listing the projects to release yields the same output, ie:
$ nx release --projects sales-orders-web company-web --dry-run --skip-publish

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?
Thanks,
Grant

I (nievly) thought that if I pushed an empty commit as 'fix(company-web): ...', it would be picked up as a patch to that project, but obviously that doesnt work.

I found this issue (https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/26041) and associated reproducer project (https://github.com/JamesHenry/nx-26041) that helped solve this same problem for me.
The key parts were to include the following snippet in the nx.json
{
    "release": {
        "generatorOptions": {
            "updateDependents": "auto"

        }
    }
}

And include a reference to the library in each application project package.json
{
    "name": "@repo/app1",
    "dependencies": {
        "@repo/lib": "x.x.x."
    }
}

After including these changes the nx release command would release and publish both the changed library and the indirectly impacted application.

Thanks @Tim, much appricated. I've also been following that ticket, but it the solution Jame's presented did not work for me. I've added some more info about my situation on that ticket, hopefully it helps. G

The issue is resolved. I had not setup my libraries with package.json files, so they didnt have versions, which means they couldnt be processes by nx release.
Thanksl

For anyone else who lands here, the @nx/dependency-checks rule will only work on projects with a build target.  So, make sure your package is buildable so that this rule can automatically maintain a thorough and correct list of deps in the package.json for you.
